# Vogel's approximation algorithm in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, algorithm

I have very little experience with Java and am trying to use my little knowledge to interpret some java source code i found online [here](http://getpocket.com/redirect?url=http%3A%2F%2Frosettacode.org%2Fwiki%2FVogel%5C's_approximation_method) for Vogel's approximation algorithm into javascript with no luck.

PS: There is also source code for python in the link.
worker.js

```
var scope = self;
var thread = {
    sum: function ( items) {
        total = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            total = total+items[i];
        }

        return total;
    },

    min: function (costs) {
        return Math.min.apply(Math, costs);
    },

    min2: function (costs, min) {
        j = []
        for(var i = 0; i<costs.length; i++) {
            if(costs[i] > min) {
                j.push(costs[i]);
            }
        }

        return Math.min.apply(Math, j);
    },

    vam: function (demand, supply, costs) {
        var nRows = supply.length;
        var ncols = demand.length;

        var supplyLeft = this.sum(supply);
        var totalCost = 0;

        //stuck here
    },
}

self.onmessage = function(e) {
    thread.vam(e.data.demand, e.data.supply, e.data.costs);
}
```

This is section of java source i dont understand

```
static int[] nextCell() throws Exception {
        Future<int[]> f1 = es.submit(() -> maxPenalty(nRows, nCols, true));
        Future<int[]> f2 = es.submit(() -> maxPenalty(nCols, nRows, false));

        int[] res1 = f1.get();
        int[] res2 = f2.get();

        if (res1[3] == res2[3])
            return res1[2] < res2[2] ? res1 : res2;

        return (res1[3] > res2[3]) ? res2 : res1;
    }

    static int[] diff(int j, int len, boolean isRow) {
        int min1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE, min2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int minP = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (isRow ? colDone[i] : rowDone[i])
                continue;
            int c = isRow ? costs[j][i] : costs[i][j];
            if (c < min1) {
                min2 = min1;
                min1 = c;
                minP = i;
            } else if (c < min2)
                min2 = c;
        }
        return new int[]{min2 - min1, min1, minP};
    }

    static int[] maxPenalty(int len1, int len2, boolean isRow) {
        int md = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int pc = -1, pm = -1, mc = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
            if (isRow ? rowDone[i] : colDone[i])
                continue;
            int[] res = diff(i, len2, isRow);
            if (res[0] > md) {
                md = res[0];  // max diff
                pm = i;       // pos of max diff
                mc = res[1];  // min cost
                pc = res[2];  // pos of min cost
            }
        }
        return isRow ? new int[]{pm, pc, mc, md} : new int[]{pc, pm, mc, md};
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: @RealSkeptic i've been able to create an interface for data entry and a method to get data from the fields

Comment: It would be best if you post just a small portion that you're struggling to understand and convert; I believe people will be more likely to help if they see something other than what appears to be a massive code dump.

Comment: Interesting link you provided. I noticed that the different implementations (on that page) give different solutions and mostly the same cost: 3100. The python however came up with a cost of 3130. Perhaps it might be a better idea to first decide on exactly what algorithm you want to implement (in javascript) instead of translating one of those (which are assumable optimized to language's environment and possibly the understanding and/or required accuracy of the programmer who coded the example).

Comment: Well the algorithm is for computing minimum transportation costs, so am going for the implementation with the least cost which is java

Comment: assuming you understand basic ternaries and arrays, you can pretty much copy the maxPenalty and diff function right? Likewise, the second half of nextCell function. That leaves you with the Future (those are threads is what I have just googled) and Integer.MAX_VALUE (which should be unsigned 32 bit, so you could hard code that for identical output). If you disregard the future (I love this sentence, its on par with 'this' is your problem), and view the program as a single thread, it's pretty clear what it does. Assuming this helps you, or please describe more clearly what you don't understand.